# How to hide (or remove) Action Bar at run time in android application

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I have created an application. There is a login activity so I just want to remove the action bar at runtime.
What should I do ???

See [image: Screenshot]

You can see in the image blue action bar. I just want to remove this only.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the AppCompatActivity, then you can perform action:

```
// to hide the action bar
getSupportActionBar().hide();
// to show the action bar
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

If you are using the Activity, then you can perform action:

```
// to hide the action bar
getActionBar().hide();
// to show the action bar
getActionBar().show();
```

**Note**: This work only of You are using the **Theme** with `Action Bar`.

Comment: Thanks Problem solved.

Comment: Can you Please accept the answer if it works for you TIA